# simpleSAMLphp with multi-app and config

Tags: php, configuration, saml

I have setup a simplesaml installation and configured my sources, 
I made themes for those APPs (login page) to look the same as before.

Now I wont to load those themes based on application, the problem is that this is defined in

```
/config/config.php

 'theme.use'        => 'default'
```

and I need to heve more then one.

```
'theme.use'         => 'mod1:app1'
'theme.use'         => 'mod2:app2'
and so on...
```

how can this be done? 
In a nutshell: like a config for every application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some answers:

> can multiple sites have thair own (login) template ?

**Not on the same simpleSAMLphp installation.**

> can auth be checked aganst all providers  (Ldap, local mysql, rest
>   web service...)?

**There is no support for that.**

**Source:** http://groups.google.com/group/simplesamlphp/browse_thread/thread/2541a915b9e10bef